# A production-ready, real-time recommendation engine thats easy to setup

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I want to store large number of data ppints for user actions, like likes, tags etc (I have plans for both e-commerce and document management).

With the data points, I want to support functions such as

1. "users who loved X loved Y,Z" recommendations
2. "fetch more stuff similar to X,Y" clustering.

---

By production-ready, real-time; I mean that I can enter data points and make queries at the same time, the server will take care of answering queries and updating scores by itself.

---

I searched around the interwebs and the solutions that come up are either of:

1. Data-mining libraries that are mostly academic-oriented and are meant for large batch operations, **not for heavy real-time queries**
2. Hadoop/Mahout, which is production-ready and support real time updates and queries, but **have a steep learning curve** and tough to administer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For recommenders, Mahout has a non-distributed recommender implementation that does not use Hadoop. In fact, this is the only part that is real-time; the Hadoop-based parts are not.

I think there is little learning curve to it; see [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/recommender-documentation.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/unresyst/wiki/CreateMahoutRecommender) for a pretty complete writeup.

[Mahout in Action](http://manning.com/owen/) chapters 2-5 cover this quite well too.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that for useful recommendations, the various parameters of such a system must be carefully fine tuned. The out of the box functionality many systems have (Oracle data mining, Microsoft data mining extensions etc.) just offer the core functionality.

So in the end, you will not get around the "steep learning curve", I guess. That is why you need experts for data mining. If there were a point-and-click solution, it would already be integrated everywhere.

Example "similar items". I laughed hard, when Amazon once recommended me to buy two products: Debian Linux Administrators Handbook and ... Debian Linux Admininstrators Handbook WITH CD.

I hope you get the key point of this example: to a plain algorithm, the two books appear "similar", and thus a sensible combination. To a human, it it pointless to buy the same book twice. You need to *teach* such rules to any recommendation system, as they cannot be trivially learned from the data. There will always be good results and useless results, and you need to tune and parameterize the system carefully.